# Mysql is not connecting with node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '127.0.0.1',
  user     : 'mohit',
  password : 'abcd',
  database : 'sampleDb',
  port:'3306'
});
 
connection.connect(function(err){
    if(err)
    console.log("Error in connecting Mysql");
    else
    console.log("Connected");
});
```

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
connection.query("Select * from Book",function(err,rows,fields){
if(err)
console.log("Error in query");
else
console.log("Success Query");
});
})

I am getting error in connection.connect it is consoling me Error in connecting Mysql
But with this credantials I am able to access my database in mysql

Comment: Try via command prompt whether you are able to connect or using a different client program like mysql work bench with all the above credentials and connect to same DB.

Comment: print the err in console, so you can understand the error msg, console.log("Error in connecting Mysql and error details ", err);

Comment: Thanks for highlighting I have resolved my error yeah!

Comment: Thats Great, If you find the solution is useful, press the "up vote" icon (above the flag icon in the comments)